# C++ Compare Two Text Files' Contexts

Tags: c++

I want to read orders from order.txt which is;

```
Chocolate Chip Cookies  1   2 
Orange Jelly Candy      2   7
Chocolate ice cream     3   11
Cake Mix Cookies        1   10
```

And decide if there is enough product from stock.txt which is;

```
Name    Type    ItemCount       Price
Chocolate Chip Cookies  1       4       600
Orange Jelly Candy      2       5       150
Cake Mix Cookies        1       12      180
Peanut Butter Chocolate Chip Cookies    1   3   120
Chocolate ice cream     3       2       240
Gummi bears     2       15      300
Raspberry Ripple        3       12      250
```

Alignment is given like that. What is the best way to do it? Is there anything to read from a file which I can store in a way like product name/ number/ price?

Thank you.

Comment: That's why I asked "What is the best way?", not "best code".

Comment: The best way is to *try writing some code*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what the second and third column signify, I assume one of them is order size.

There are many ways to do this and my method might not be the best in all cases but at least it should work in yours:

1. Read the `stock.txt` file, you can look at this [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/13087/) but it doesn't really matter what method you use. The important thing is to get the information as a variable into the program. Hopefully your text files uses a tab to separate the fields (this information is lost in the question).
2. Put the information you get into a [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/), call it `orders`, use the name as `key` and the `ItemCount` as value.
3. Now read the information in `order.txt`, use the `key` to look up the `value` in your `orders`.
4. Check that `ItemCount` is at least a large as the order size.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works.

Comment: @DoğukanArslan The question doesn't specify it but it's a good thing to consider: what if the same Item is mentioned twice in `orders.txt`?

Answer (score -1):

In a real world application you would use a Database to store the data of your stock and would write a class order which gets its values from the databas. However i dont think you want to have that much effort so here's a esier way: 
Your stock data gets saved in a simple excel table and the order is a textfile 
Order.txt:

```
Beer 1|Paint 5|Oil 3|.....
```

Use the `|` as markers to create substrings of the individual products in the order 
Bsp. ProductName quantity id|ProductName2 quantity id2|....

As for the excel table you have to to a little research yourself but editing files with a filereader isn't that hard though.

Hope i can help

Comment: Thank you for this different approach.